# how to update nested attribute in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wanna update the nested attribute but failed, for example there is a Article, and a book has many comments. when I find the comment I have written has some mistakes, so I wanna modify it.
here is my code.

In `code_snippet.rb`:

```
class CodeSnippet < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :annotations, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :annotations ,update_only: true ,reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

In `annotation.rb`:

```
class Annotation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :code_snippet

end
```

In `code_snippet_controller.rb`:

```
  def edit
    @code_snippet = CodeSnippet.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @code_snippet = CodeSnippet.find(params[:id])
    if @code_snippet.update(code_snippet_params)
      redirect_to @code_snippet
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

 private
    def code_snippet_params
      params.require(:code_snippet).permit(:snippet)
    end
```

In `annotation.rb`:

```
  def edit
    @code_snippet = CodeSnippet.find(params[:code_snippet_id])
    @annotation = @code_snippet.annotations.find(params[:id])
  end
  def update
    @code_snippet = CodeSnippet.find(params[:id])
    @annotation = @code_snippet.annotations.find(params[:id])
    if @annotation.update(annotation_params)
      redirect_to @code_snippet
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

In 'views/code_snippets/show.html.rb'

```
<div>
    <h2>Annotations</h2>
<%= render @code_snippet.annotations %>
</div>
```

In 'views/annotations/_annotation.html.erb'

```
<p>
  <strong>User:</strong>
  <%= annotation.user %>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Line:</strong>
  <%= annotation.line %>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Body:</strong>
  <%= annotation.body %>
</p>

<p>

  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_code_snippet_annotation_path(annotation.code_snippet,annotation) ,controller: 'annotation'%>
</p>
```

In 'views/annotations/edit.html.erb':

```
<%= form_for(@code_snippet) do |f| %>


    <%= f.fields_for :annotation,method: :patch do |builder| %>

        <p>
          <%= builder.label :user %><br>
          <%= builder.text_field :user %>
        </p>

        <p>
          <%= builder.label :line %><br>
          <%= builder.text_field :line %>
        </p>

        <p>
          <%= builder.label :body %><br>
          <%= builder.text_area :body %>
        </p>

        <p>
          <%= builder.submit %>
        </p>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

what I wanna update the annotation without change the codesnippets. what should I do to change my code.

Answer (score 0):

So.... There's a lot going on here so I'm going to start by suggesting a careful look at the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

Firstly, let's look at your form:
CodeSnippet has_many :annotations

So your fields_for statement should be for :annotations, not :annotation. The fields for statement also should not take a method options key.

Next your code_snippets_controller:
As indicated by the docs, the parameter sent back from the nested attributes form will be under the key: `annotations_attributes` and will contain a hash of arrays.

You need to allow this attribute, and any attribute you wish to pass onto the annotation model with strong parameters:

`params.require(:code_snippet).permit(annotations_attributes: [:some, : permitted, :params])`

I believe this is all you need to get your example working. But, if you run into more troubles, I recommend a spending some quality time with a few `binding.pry` statements to introspect on the actual behaviour of your code.

Comment: It doesn't work, if I change the field_for for annotations, it will show all the annotations of the codesnippet, I just wanna modify one of it . And I have add annotations_params in code_snippet_params by doing this:
```
 private
    def code_snippet_params
      params.require(:code_snippet).permit(:snippet,annotations_params: [:user, :line, :body])
    end
```